# Equation of plane

Tags: calculus

> Find the equation of the plane through the point $(1,−1,2)$ which is
>   perpendicular to the curve of intersection of the two surfaces
>   $x^2+y^2−z=0$ and $2x^2+3y^2+z^2−9=0$.

i've gotten as far as subbing one equation into the other but i'm stuck on the differentiation. it would be much appreciated if someone could help with this

Comment: Can you add some information about what you get when subbing into the equation, and what you are differentiating?

Comment: i changed the first equation to

z = x^2 + y^2

and subbed that into the second equation to get

x^4 + y^4 + 2x^2y^2 + 2x^2 + 3y^2 - 9 = 0

and I was told to use implicit differentiation to obtain an equation for dydx but this is where i got confused

Answer (score 0):

*Outline*: If we substitute in this way:
$$2\overbrace{(z-y^2)}^{x^2}+3y^2+z^2-9=0$$
and 
$$2x^2+3\overbrace{(z-x^2)}^{y^2}+z^2-9=0$$
we can obtain equations for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$.  So the curve through the point $(1,-1,2)$ can be parameterized by $$\big(\sqrt{\text{function of } t},-\sqrt{\text{function of } t},t\big)$$ and the derivative of this vector when $t=2$ (i.e., $z=2$) will be normal to the plane.  Given a normal vector, and a point $(1,-1,2)$ on the plane, we can determine the equation of the plane.